# How to run command automatically for every new file opened in Vim

Tags: c, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have to edit a bunch of files in a programming language that has C-like syntax (and which may or may not be used only within the confines of my university).

To get syntax highlighting without going through the hassle of creating a new syntax configuration in Vim, I just use `:set syntax=c` to force the C syntax highlighting.

To get this automatically, I `set syntax=c` in my `.vimrc` file. The problem is, whenever I open a new file in a new window with `:sp` or `:vsp`, there is no syntax highlighting, which indicates that the `set` command in my `.vimrc` is only executed when I first open Vim itself.

How do I make it so this gets executed for every new file opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vim load syntax highlight file according to filetype. usually it is judged by file name extension. ex. if your programming language file with extension as `.mine`, you should add following configuration to .vimrc

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.mine   set filetype=c
```

You can refer to [filetype.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/filetype.txt) for more tricks.

Comment: The command doesn't seem to have any effect, I'll look into it though.

Comment: @lalilulelo, maybe you should read [syntax.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/syntax.txt) for making your own syntax files too.

Comment: @lalilulelo this is definitly the right way to go, what is your fileending?

Comment: @lalilulelo: There was an extra space in between the event names; I've fixed that.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, Thanks.

Comment: Oh, it works now with the fix! Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for belongs in your `~/.vimrc`. You don't need to set syntax to a specific file type, all you need is:

```
syntax on
```

That will invoke syntax highlighting for each file you open -- with the proper syntax file (vim is pretty smart...)

You can see the effect before you modify your `~/.vimrc` simply by issuing the following within vim in command-mode

```
:syntax on
```

Comment: I already have `syntax on` set in my `vimrc`, but of course I don't have a syntax file for this particular programming language -- that's something I was trying to avoid messing with. Since the syntax is quite C-like it suffices to just use the C syntax, and thus my usage of `set syntax=c`, which does work. My only problem -- and it's a really minor one -- is with opening with this syntax highlighting automatically at each new file I open in a same given Vim session.

Comment: I apologize, it appeared you were looking for `syntax on`. Does the file have a distinct file extension or file type?

Comment: It's alright. It's a text file with an `.mn` extension. I suspect the programming language itself was created by my professor "in-house" for usage in a Norma register machine simulator. Anyway, my problem has been solved by @gzh's answer.